# Stored Procedure Executed in ADF Pipeline - Perfomance Issues

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I am going to post this question divided in sections. Your help would be much appreciated!

### Overview of the Issue

I have an issue with data refresh. Right now, I have a pipeline running on Azure Data Factory which is composed of 7 blocks. Each block hosts a stored procedure coded in SQL. Each block generates a table used by the next block. Tables average 3GB in weight. Each block takes between one and *five* hours to execute.

### What I did so far

Given that I am pretty new to this world, I tried to abide by best practices. For example, each statement begins with `SET NOCOUNT ON`. I always specified column names in select statement, avoiding code blocks like `SELECT * FROM TABLE`. Also, each table has well defined Primary Keys (defined in the same order for each table) and, being SQL server, they also act as clustered indexes. As for the exemple reported below, these are two screenshots of the indexes:

[image]

and

[image]

I tried to exploit the `MERGE` statement. An example of one stored procedure is reported below. Note that I took the max() of all dimension fields because I joined sales and stock together at the level of `Week, Product, Season, and Store` and then grouped only by `Week, Product, and Season`. Hence, if I had stores that had a product but did not sale it I would have doubled the rows on `NULL` attributes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_W_LINE_LEVEL_RT_WORLD2
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE [dbo].[W_LINE_LEVEL_RT_WORLD2] AS TARGET 
USING
(
SELECT
    COALESCE(sales.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM, stock.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM) AS FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM,
    COALESCE(sales.BTN, stock.BTN_CD) AS BTN,
    COALESCE(sales.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS, stock.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS) AS ARTICLE_SEASON_DS,
    MAX(PRODUCT_IMAGE) AS PRODUCT_IMAGE,
    --MAX(SUBCHANNEL) AS SUBCHANNEL,
    MAX(GENDER) AS GENDER,
    MAX(PRODUCT_CATEGORY) AS PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    MAX(FIRST_SEASON) AS FIRST_SEASON,
    MAX(LAST_SEASON) AS LAST_SEASON,
    MAX(TREND_DS) AS TREND_DS,
    MAX(TREND_CD) AS TREND_CD,
    MAX(COLOR) AS COLOR,
    MAX(MATERIAL) AS MATERIAL,
    MAX(FINISH) AS FINISH,
    MAX(DEPARTMENT) AS DEPARTMENT,
    MAX(PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY) AS PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,
    MAX(THEME_DS) AS THEME_DS,
    MAX(THEME_FIX) AS THEME_FIX,
    MAX(PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS) AS PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS,
    MAX(PRODUCT_GROUP_DS) AS PRODUCT_GROUP_DS,
    MAX(MODEL_DS) AS MODEL_DS,
    MAX(PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS) AS PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS,
    MAX(LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE) AS LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE,
    -- AVERAGE LIFE TO DATE METRICS
    MAX(FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD) / NULLIF(MAX(TOTAL_QTY_LTD),0) AS AVERAGE_FULL_PRICE_CHF,
    MAX(NET_REVENUES_LTD) /  NULLIF(MAX(TOTAL_QTY_LTD),0) AS AVERAGE_SELLING_PRICE_CHF,
    MAX(SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD) / NULLIF(MAX(TOTAL_QTY_LTD),0) AS STANDARD_COST_CHF,
    MAX(SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD) / NULLIF(MAX(NET_REVENUES_LTD),0) AS MARGIN,
    -- WEEK BY WEEK ANALYSIS
    MAX(LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE) AS LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE,
    SUM(NET_REVENUES) AS NET_REVENUES,
    SUM(NET_SALES) AS NET_SALES,
    SUM(FULL_PRICE_SALES) AS FULL_PRICE_SALES,
    SUM(VAL_STDCOST) AS VAL_STDCOST,
    SUM(TOT_PROMOTION) AS TOT_PROMOTION,
    SUM(NET_SALES_MARKDOWN) AS NET_SALES_MARKDOWN,
    SUM(NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN) AS NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN,
    SUM(TOT_DISCOUNT) AS TOT_DISCOUNT,
    SUM(SALES_QTY) AS SALES_QTY,
    COUNT(DISTINCT STORE_SELLING) AS STORE_SELLING,
    COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(sales.CLIENT_CD, stock.CLIENT_CD)) AS TOTAL_STORES_LW,
    -- LIFE TO DATE ANALYSIS
    MAX(NET_SALES_LTD) AS NET_SALES_LTD,
    MAX(NET_REVENUES_LTD) AS NET_REVENUES_LTD,
    MAX(FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD) AS FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD,
    MAX(SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD) AS SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD,
    MAX(FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD) AS FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD,
    MAX(TOTAL_QTY_LTD) AS TOTAL_QTY_LTD,
    MAX(NET_SALES_LTD_REGION) AS NET_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    MAX(NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION) AS NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION,
    MAX(FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION) AS FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    MAX(SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION) AS SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION,
    MAX(FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION) AS FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    MAX(TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION) AS TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_SEASONAL_AW_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_CARRY_AW_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_SEASONAL_SS_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_CARRY_SS_LTD),0) AS WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD,
    COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_SEASONAL_AW_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_CARRY_AW_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_SEASONAL_SS_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_CARRY_SS_LTD_REGION),0) AS WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD_REGION,
    COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_AW_CARRY_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_AW_SEASONAL_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_SS_CARRY_LTD),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_SS_SEASONAL_LTD),0) AS STORES_SELLING_LTD,
    COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_AW_CARRY_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_AW_SEASONAL_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_SS_CARRY_LTD_REGION),0) + COALESCE(MAX(RUNNING_STORE_SELLING_SS_SEASONAL_LTD_REGION),0) AS STORES_SELLING_LTD_REGION,
    -- STOCK DATA
    COUNT(DISTINCT stock.CLIENT_CD) AS STOCK_STORES,
    SUM(STOCK_QTY_NM) AS STOCK_QTY_NM,
    SUM(STOCK_IN_STORE) AS STOCK_IN_STORE,
    SUM(STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE) AS STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE,
    SUM(STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC) AS STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC,
    SUM(STOCK_IN_STORE) + SUM(STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE) + SUM(STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE) + SUM(STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC) AS TOTAL_STOCK_ON_HAND,
    SUM(STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH) AS STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH,
    SUM(STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION) AS STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION,
    SUM(STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH) AS STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH
FROM
    W_SALES_LINE_LEVEL_RT_WORLD2 sales 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    W_STOCK_LINE_LEVEL_RT_WORLD stock
ON
    sales.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM = stock.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM
    AND sales.BTN = stock.BTN_CD
    AND sales.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS = stock.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS
    AND sales.CLIENT_CD = stock.CLIENT_CD
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(sales.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM, stock.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM),
    COALESCE(sales.BTN, stock.BTN_CD),
    COALESCE(sales.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS, stock.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS)
) NUOVA
ON 
    TARGET.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM = NUOVA.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM
    AND TARGET.BTN = NUOVA.BTN
    AND TARGET.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS = NUOVA.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET 
    TARGET.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM = NUOVA.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM,
    TARGET.BTN = NUOVA.BTN,
    TARGET.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS = NUOVA.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_IMAGE = NUOVA.PRODUCT_IMAGE,
    --TARGET.SUBCHANNEL = NUOVA.SUBCHANNEL,
    TARGET.GENDER = NUOVA.GENDER,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_CATEGORY = NUOVA.PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    TARGET.FIRST_SEASON = NUOVA.FIRST_SEASON,
    TARGET.LAST_SEASON = NUOVA.LAST_SEASON,
    TARGET.TREND_DS = NUOVA.TREND_DS,
    TARGET.TREND_CD = NUOVA.TREND_CD,
    TARGET.COLOR = NUOVA.COLOR,
    TARGET.MATERIAL = NUOVA.MATERIAL,
    TARGET.FINISH = NUOVA.FINISH,
    TARGET.DEPARTMENT = NUOVA.DEPARTMENT,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY = NUOVA.PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,
    TARGET.THEME_DS = NUOVA.THEME_DS,
    TARGET.THEME_FIX = NUOVA.THEME_FIX,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS = NUOVA.PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_GROUP_DS = NUOVA.PRODUCT_GROUP_DS,
    TARGET.MODEL_DS = NUOVA.MODEL_DS,
    TARGET.PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS = NUOVA.PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS,
    TARGET.LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE = NUOVA.LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE,
    TARGET.AVERAGE_FULL_PRICE_CHF = NUOVA.AVERAGE_FULL_PRICE_CHF,
    TARGET.AVERAGE_SELLING_PRICE_CHF = NUOVA.AVERAGE_SELLING_PRICE_CHF,
    TARGET.STANDARD_COST_CHF = NUOVA.STANDARD_COST_CHF,
    TARGET.MARGIN = NUOVA.MARGIN,
    TARGET.LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE = NUOVA.LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE,
    TARGET.NET_REVENUES = NUOVA.NET_REVENUES,
    TARGET.NET_SALES = NUOVA.NET_SALES,
    TARGET.FULL_PRICE_SALES = NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES,
    TARGET.VAL_STDCOST = NUOVA.VAL_STDCOST,
    TARGET.TOT_PROMOTION = NUOVA.TOT_PROMOTION,
    TARGET.NET_SALES_MARKDOWN = NUOVA.NET_SALES_MARKDOWN,
    TARGET.NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN = NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN,
    TARGET.TOT_DISCOUNT = NUOVA.TOT_DISCOUNT,
    TARGET.SALES_QTY = NUOVA.SALES_QTY,
    TARGET.STORE_SELLING = NUOVA.STORE_SELLING,
    TARGET.TOTAL_STORES_LW = NUOVA.TOTAL_STORES_LW,
    TARGET.NET_SALES_LTD = NUOVA.NET_SALES_LTD,
    TARGET.NET_REVENUES_LTD = NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_LTD,
    TARGET.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD = NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD,
    TARGET.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD = NUOVA.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD,
    TARGET.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD = NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD,
    TARGET.TOTAL_QTY_LTD = NUOVA.TOTAL_QTY_LTD,
    TARGET.NET_SALES_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.NET_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD = NUOVA.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD,
    TARGET.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.STORES_SELLING_LTD = NUOVA.STORES_SELLING_LTD,
    TARGET.STORES_SELLING_LTD_REGION = NUOVA.STORES_SELLING_LTD_REGION,
    TARGET.STOCK_STORES = NUOVA.STOCK_STORES,
    TARGET.STOCK_QTY_NM = NUOVA.STOCK_QTY_NM,
    TARGET.STOCK_IN_STORE = NUOVA.STOCK_IN_STORE,
    TARGET.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE = NUOVA.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE,
    TARGET.STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC = NUOVA.STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC,
    TARGET.TOTAL_STOCK_ON_HAND = NUOVA.TOTAL_STOCK_ON_HAND,
    TARGET.STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH = NUOVA.STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH,
    TARGET.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION = NUOVA.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION,
    TARGET.STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH = NUOVA.STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT 
    (FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM,
    BTN,
    ARTICLE_SEASON_DS,
    PRODUCT_IMAGE,
    --SUBCHANNEL,
    GENDER,
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    FIRST_SEASON,
    LAST_SEASON,
    TREND_DS,
    TREND_CD,
    COLOR,
    MATERIAL,
    FINISH,
    DEPARTMENT,
    PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,
    THEME_DS,
    THEME_FIX,
    PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS,
    PRODUCT_GROUP_DS,
    MODEL_DS,
    PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS,
    LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE,
    AVERAGE_FULL_PRICE_CHF,
    AVERAGE_SELLING_PRICE_CHF,
    STANDARD_COST_CHF,
    MARGIN,
    LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE,
    NET_REVENUES,
    NET_SALES,
    FULL_PRICE_SALES,
    VAL_STDCOST,
    TOT_PROMOTION,
    NET_SALES_MARKDOWN,
    NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN,
    TOT_DISCOUNT,
    SALES_QTY,
    STORE_SELLING,
    TOTAL_STORES_LW,
    NET_SALES_LTD,
    NET_REVENUES_LTD,
    FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD,
    SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD,
    FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD,
    TOTAL_QTY_LTD,
    NET_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION,
    FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION,
    FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD,
    WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD_REGION,
    STORES_SELLING_LTD,
    STORES_SELLING_LTD_REGION,
    STOCK_STORES,
    STOCK_QTY_NM,
    STOCK_IN_STORE,
    STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE,
    STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC,
    TOTAL_STOCK_ON_HAND,
    STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH,
    STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION,
    STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH)
    VALUES 
    (NUOVA.FISCAL_YEARWEEK_NM,
    NUOVA.BTN,
    NUOVA.ARTICLE_SEASON_DS,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_IMAGE,
    --NUOVA.SUBCHANNEL,
    NUOVA.GENDER,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    NUOVA.FIRST_SEASON,
    NUOVA.LAST_SEASON,
    NUOVA.TREND_DS,
    NUOVA.TREND_CD,
    NUOVA.COLOR,
    NUOVA.MATERIAL,
    NUOVA.FINISH,
    NUOVA.DEPARTMENT,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,
    NUOVA.THEME_DS,
    NUOVA.THEME_FIX,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_SUBGROUP_DS,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_GROUP_DS,
    NUOVA.MODEL_DS,
    NUOVA.PRODUCT_FAMILY_DS,
    NUOVA.LAST_YEAR_WEEK_ABILITAZIONE,
    NUOVA.AVERAGE_FULL_PRICE_CHF,
    NUOVA.AVERAGE_SELLING_PRICE_CHF,
    NUOVA.STANDARD_COST_CHF,
    NUOVA.MARGIN,
    NUOVA.LAST_YEAR_MOTNH_ABILITAZIONE,
    NUOVA.NET_REVENUES,
    NUOVA.NET_SALES,
    NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES,
    NUOVA.VAL_STDCOST,
    NUOVA.TOT_PROMOTION,
    NUOVA.NET_SALES_MARKDOWN,
    NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_MARKDOWN,
    NUOVA.TOT_DISCOUNT,
    NUOVA.SALES_QTY,
    NUOVA.STORE_SELLING,
    NUOVA.TOTAL_STORES_LW,
    NUOVA.NET_SALES_LTD,
    NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_LTD,
    NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD,
    NUOVA.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD,
    NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD,
    NUOVA.TOTAL_QTY_LTD,
    NUOVA.NET_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.NET_REVENUES_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_SALES_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.SALES_VALUE_STD_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.FULL_PRICE_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.TOTAL_QTY_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD,
    NUOVA.WEEKS_ON_FLOOR_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.STORES_SELLING_LTD,
    NUOVA.STORES_SELLING_LTD_REGION,
    NUOVA.STOCK_STORES,
    NUOVA.STOCK_QTY_NM,
    NUOVA.STOCK_IN_STORE,
    NUOVA.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_STORE,
    NUOVA.STOCK_IN_REGIONAL_DC,
    NUOVA.TOTAL_STOCK_ON_HAND,
    NUOVA.STOCK_ALLOCATED_IN_CENTRAL_WH,
    NUOVA.STOCK_IN_TRANSIT_TO_REGION,
    NUOVA.STOCK_FREE_CENTRAL_WH)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;
```

### The Road Ahead

Now, the query reported above alone took five hours to complete. I am sure there are better ways out there to improve this terrible performance. I hope some of you will land a hand here.

If I can be clearer on something, just drop a comment!

Thanks!

Comment: `FULL JOIN` is usually slow, do you really need it or can you manage with a `LEFT JOIN`? You can then also `GROUP BY` only one of the values . And `ISNULL` is faster than `COALESCE`. You are merging with source and target being the same table so it's unclear what logic you are trying to achieve. The table looks far too wide, are you sure you need all those column or could some of them be normalized or computed? For further help we need to see full index definitions and the query plan (you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. I need to use `FULL JOIN` because the business needs to see also which products they have in stock that didn't sell. I'll follow the `ISNULL` option. I am merging the same table with itself because I need to have the same transformations in the refreshed table. All fileds are considered necessary... Tried to get the business on getting rid of something but didn't convince them. As for the query plan, unfortunately I do not have permission to run SHOWPLAN (`SHOWPLAN permission denied in database`). Do you know any other way to get it?

Comment: But do you have any sold products which don't have stock? If not you can `LEFT JOIN` the other way round. Ask your DBA to give you permissions to do the work you need to do `GRANT SHOWPLAN TO YourUserName`. *"I need to have the same transformations in the refreshed table"* I don;t know what that means, please elaborate

Comment: I'll do that. As for the index definistions, I am updating my question. Yes, I do have "sold out" products.

"I need to have the same transformations in the refreshed table": I am not just taking on new, fresh data.  I am performing some transofrmations that are needed in subsequent tables (e.g. the `GROUP BY` clause). Also, other Stored Procedures in the pipeline perform many more transformations. Hope this is clear, if not tell me.

Comment: Are you married to the `merge` statement by business requirements? The `merge` statement can cause a bit of religious contention. I tend to use it where it works, but there are several caveats around it: [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), updated by [What To Avoid If You Want To Use MERGE](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/). To get access to execution plans are you able to work on these operations with restored data on a different database instance?

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I could not manage to get my username authorized to run the showplan command. However, I did find something really interesting at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284887/optimize-mysql-full-outer-join-for-massive-amount-of-data/22285348#comment123726790_22285348). Using the logic of left and right join we could meet the requirement.